# Extending material-ui SpeedDial component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

#### What I would like to do

Adding / extending existing functionality of the Speed Dial component. (refactoring into my own component)

#### What doesn't work

When I try to wrap the `SpeedDial` component inside my own component and embed it into a class or functional component it throws an error about invalid React Hooks.

#### how to reproduce this issue

> 1. Setup a main class or functional component
> 2. Setup a class or functional wrapper component around Material-UI SpeedDial
> 3. Implement the wrapper component inside the main (App.js) component
> 4. Results in an invalid hook call.

#### Dummy setup

```
// FAB.js
function FloatingActionButton (props) {
  return (
    <SpeedDial>
      <SpeedDialAction />
      <SpeedDialAction />
      <SpeedDialAction />
    </SpeedDial>
  )
}

// App.js
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    <FloatingActionButton />
  }
}
```

#### Important note

For all other components such as Button, Modal etc the above implementation just works. Probably because they do not yet implement react hooks.